# Mp3 encoder for android, record audio in mp3 format

Tags: android, mp3, audio-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encode a WAV to a mp3 on a Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device)

I want to record audio in MP3 format in my android application. I know I can read PCM audio using the audioRecord class. Is there a java library compatible with android that will encode PCM to MP3? Is it possible to use the Lame mp3 encoder library?

Comment: I answered a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device/

Comment: You can use libav with LAME mp3 and you can find example http://libavandroid.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/record-mp3-in-android-using-libavffmpeg/