# Encoding raw audio to mp3/ogg

Tags: java, android

I have a buffer of raw audio coming from AudioRecord and I want to convert it to mp3 or any other format for emailing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode a WAV to a mp3 on a Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably compile http://lame.sourceforge.net/ as a jni library.

Be sure to read and understand http://lame.sourceforge.net/license.txt

I'm sure someone has some java encoder you could use if you aren't talking about tons of data.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at JLayer (http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) from JavaZoom. It's 100% Java and I think it will do what you want.

Good luck.

Comment: As far as I understand javalayer is decoder only - not encoding. maybe I'm wrong.