# Android convert pcm file from AudioRecord to smaller file

Tags: android, compression, audio, pcm

I tried to record audio in Android. The quality of the sound using the MediaRecorder really sucks.

So I tried writing the sound to a stream using the AudioRecord function. Great quality but pcm-files are too large in size as I want to upload them to a remote server.

Does anybody know how to compress the pcm (like mp3 or else)?
Any help is mostly appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no built-in audio converters in Android. Your best bet is to use third party library, maybe even a c/c++ one.

Look at this question for more info: [How to encode a WAV to a mp3 on a Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920)

Comment: I was half expecting that. Thanks anyway!