# Android: How to Convert MP4A audio into MP3 or Wav using Java

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3

Android cannot record mp3 audio using the MediaRecorder but it can record mp4a. I'm trying to figure out a way to convert mp4a audio into mp3 on my Android phone. I believe this means FFMPEG is not an option since it needs to be done on the phone. What are my options?

Comment: Similar type of question here with my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692330/127938

Answer (score 0):

Currently it looks like you are limited to only three choices:

-MPEG4 
-AMR
-3GPP

It looks like there is an open issue on it for you to track.  I gave it a vote for you also.
[Android only records audio into proprietary AMR format](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8848)