# Record voice as mp3 in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, mediarecorder

In my android application, I want to record my voice as an MP3 file. But Android's `Media Recorder` (class that supports audio recording) does not seem to support MP3 format. It seems to allow only 3gp and mpeg4 file formats.

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG4);
```

Can anyone help me out or give me a code ?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4886365/1321873

Answer (score 1):

Mp3 encoder is not available in android, But mp3 can be encoded using Libav/FFMPeg with mp3 LAME and you can find example code [here](http://libavandroid.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/record-mp3-in-android-using-libavffmpeg/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this is work for me:

```
MediaRecorder   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
/*  recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);*/
recorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
```

Answer (score -2):

MP3 is officially supported by android now :

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Core Media Formats:

---

Format / Codec   **||**      Details       **||**      Supported File Type(s) / Container Formats

---

MP3        **||**      Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or variable bit-rate (VBR)       **||**     MP3 (.mp3)Formats

---

[image]

You can use it as :

**mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);**

and save the file with suffix "**.mp3**"

Comment: This is just wrong. MP3 its not supported as encoder (recording) as you can see with the little dot in your own picture (missing the table titles). What matters is the AudioEncoder. The OutputFormat and the extension are unrelated; you can name an audio file .jpg if you please to.