# Android : Record sound in mp3 format

Tags: android, mp3, record

I am building an android app, having feature of capturing sound through microphone and playing it through headphone. For this, I have used "AudioRecord" and "AudioTrack". Following is some part of code that I am using,(just for understanding)

```
mInBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat);
mOutBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat);
mAudioInput = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat,
            mInBufferSize);
mAudioOutput = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat,
            mOutBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

But the main problem is that I want to record incoming sound in mp3 format? Please help me in this, I will really appreciate...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 52):

There's a work around for saving .mp3 files using MediaRecorder. Here's how:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.mp3");
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

The important part here is the `setOuputFormat` and the `setAudioEncoder`. Apparently MediaRecorder records playable mp3 if you're using `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4` and `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC` together. Hope this helps somebody.

Of course, if you'd rather use the AudioRecorder class I think the source code Chirag linked below should work just fine - https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid (although you might need to translate some of it from Japanese to English)

**Edit:** As Bruno, and a few others pointed out in the comments, this does *not encode* the file in MP3. The encoding is still AAC. However, if you try to play a sound, saved using a .mp3 extension via the code above, it will still play without issues because most media players are smart enough to detect the real encoding.

Comment: I am surprised that most developers aren't aware as how easy it is to record mp3! Thanks!

Comment: Using the AudioEnconder.ACC has some weird effects on some devices...for some reason was recording audio to fast on a Lenovo Tab3 with Android 6.0. I ended up using MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB and worked well for me.

Comment: sorry, but this DOES NOT produce MP3-encoded files. they are still aac-encoded (at leaat on my galaxy s6)

Comment: Guys, just because you name the extension of the file MP3, it doesn't make it MP3! It's AAC encoded and devices, which don't support AAC, will not play it! So this is not a workaround and this should not be upvoted!

Comment: you'll want to use the .m4a extension - that's the actual extension and is well accepted across most platforms (iOS, web)

Comment: Some software will not recognize a file saved like this as an mp3 file, e.g., Audacity (2022).

Answer (score 11):

Here on git you can find source code for Mp3 Voice Recorder Sample For Android .

[Checkout](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid) this source code.

Comment: That's really good answer and I am ready to accept it, but the problem is that it affects "AudioTrack",  I mean after using this code, I am not able to listen sound in headphone.  Can these both processes be in parellel?, like playing sound using "AudioTrack" and recording it into mp3? thanks for the answer

Comment: You can use Media Player Class to listen it in headphone.

Comment: Yeah, but MediaPlayer is useful after completion of recording, but In this case requirement is to play sound and record it simulataneously

Comment: as far as I know , android under 4 do not allow you play voice at it records

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me, I've found exactly what I needed.

Comment: This project may be better: https://github.com/talzeus/AndroidMp3Recorder , it is with no Japanese characters. Both of them use mp3lame library.

Comment: @Richard How can I use the above link in my project? anyway to compile it  via gradle etc. ?? please help

Comment: @Sha You need to set up the compile environment on a linux system.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. but if it will help someone I created a repository with an android java full recording app demo, the output file is an mp3 file.
keep in mind, I set the target sdk to 21 if to eliminate the need for requesting user permission. this is only for the demo purposes.
you can clone and use it.

Most of the code I used is from this repo: [this](https://github.com/GinRyan/AndroidMp3LameRecorderCompat64)

My demo repo:
[mp3 recording app](https://github.com/eliranRP/MP3Recording)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `outputformat` of the recorder as `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT`. I have used this and the resulting audio file is an mp3.

Comment: Hi.  I tried this and 'adb pull'ed the result to my linux development host.  File on the resultant file gives:/home/sjs/AudioDemo.mp3: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, 3GPP.  i.e. the file is an mp4 file.  Device was a Nexus 7 running Android 6.0.1.  Sorry & thanks.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath() + "/record.mp3");
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Answer (score -3):

This is work for me

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.mp3";
    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);`
```

myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();`

Comment: This doesn't record mp3, only the extension of the file will be mo3, not the file format.