# lame mp3 encoder/decoder high battery usage in android

Tags: android, battery, lame, bass

I develop mp3 recorder application and using bass and lame libraries to record a wav and convert it to a mp3 file.

when I recording mp3 file android show a notification that say

> "This app using too much battery and close it".

**How to config lame to use less battery or how to config application to block android battery usage notification ?**

Comment: Why don't you use Androids native MediaRecorder? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985518/android-record-sound-in-mp3-format

Comment: android MediaRecorder can not record mp3 in that question you link to comment nobody accept answer and only [this](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid) record mp3 and use lame

Comment: According to the answers in the linked question it can.