# How can I record small size voice files in Android using Titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, audio, titanium, recorder

Please help me! I want to record small size voice files in Android using Titanium.

I am using Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder() to record voice files, but the size of the generated files are too large.

I would like to generate small size voice files. It doesn't matter to have low quality.

What format and what compression type should I use to get better results (small size files)?
Thank you

I am using the code below:

```
var audioRecorder = Ti.Media.createAudioRecorder({
    format: Titanium.Media.AUDIO_FILEFORMAT_MP3,
    compression: Titanium.Media.AUDIO_FORMAT_ULAW
});

function startRecord() {
    audioRecorder.start();
}

function stopRecord() {
    record = audioRecorder.stop();
    var audioName = "some_name.mp3";
    var audioFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, audioName);
    audioFile.write(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you'll see that the `compression` and `format` parameters are iOS only. Android will always record [default audio settings](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/e6757ddb92353d47e960272593f7fa00226fcaba/android/modules/media/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/media/TiAudioRecorder.java#L93-L94).

You either have to

- create a MediaRecorder module
- try one of those: http://gitt.io/search?q=audio (some are very old and need to be recompiled for Ti SDK 9)
- use Hyperloop to create a recorder. As a starting point you can have a look at [Hyperloop MediaPlayer example](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/blob/master/app/controllers/android/mediaplayer.js)

You might be able to convert this navitve [MediaRecorder example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054794/5193915) to Hyperloop.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I think I will use Hyperloop