# Appcelerator - Audio format on Android

Tags: android, audio, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm recording audio on Android. I'm using this module: https://github.com/yagitoshiro/TiAudioRecorder

With `.3gp` extension I can record and replay the audio perfectly, but I need to record this audio with `.wav` or `.mp3`. With this extension I can't replay the sound, the app can't open the audio.

I saw at the module this line:

```
this.recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

and searching on Android docs I found that ouput format only can be `3gp` or `mp4`. `wav` is not available?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not obtain on the fly mp3 encoding from MediaRecorder. Check also the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886365/androidhow-to-get-media-recorder-output-in-mp3-format) question.

You can however use third party library for post processing like [Gstreamer](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorials)

Comment: WAV you can obtain by raw (pcm) data and a specific header (bitrate,channels). For this you should use `AudioRecorder`. Here is an [example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/audio-recording-in-wav-format-in-android-programming/). MediaRecorder can only give you at best a variable rate format (AMR-NB)