# Cannot convert wav-File to flac-File with javaFlacEncoder library

Tags: java, audio, wav, flac

I have the following problem.

I record a wav file of my speech with my android device. I speak in: "1 2 3 4 5"

I can play the wav file on my pc.

I want to convert the wav file using the library javaFlacEncoder-0.2.3.jar (http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/)

Here is the code I used:

```
FLAC_FileEncoder ffe = new FLAC_FileEncoder();
ffe.encode(new File("test.wav"), new File("test.flac"));
```

The flac file is generated and I can open and hear it. The problem is, that the beginning of the audio is cut off somehow. It directly starts with "4 5" instead of "1 2 3 4 5".

So there is some audio from the beginning of the wav file missing.

When I convert the same wav file by using this service: http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-flac

I get a flac file back and it is converted correctly ( I hear "1 2 3 4 5", so the whole audio.)

Do you know where the problem could be?
Or is there another easy to use library for wav2flac?

Greetings,
Subby

Comment: Maybe it's better to convert it in mp3. Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device/

Comment: Maybe it is better, but useless for me.

Comment: javaFlacEncoder depends on javax.sound library, which is not supported in Android.  How have you successfully encoded to a FLAC using it?